# How to do some action after selecting a section in a table view in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I have a tableView, which contains 5 sections, each section contains only one row, I have inserted a customView on each row, The view consists of name and mobile number, when a section is selected, the name and mob. no. should of the "corresponding section" be passed to the next view.

I have inserted the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can show what you have tried? and can you show the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is used to select a row in a section, but I am having only one row in each section, the action should happen according to the section selcted.

Comment: Why do you want to do with section selected not row selected?

Comment: I want to select the row only, but, didSelectRowAtIndexPath method can be used only when there is more no. of rows, but I have only one row

Comment: @chandru even if you only have one row. you are still selecting that row. and maybe you can show how you call the next view it will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: Ya, I am selecting a row, but the action should vary according to the section in which the row is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to identify the section of the row for which didSelectRowAtIndexPath is invoked. You can get the section information in an NSIndexPath object itself by accessing 'section' property

Here is the class reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int section = indexPath.section;
    //...
  }
```

Comment: Do u have any example for this

Comment: I will be adding the values dynamically, so the number of sections will increase or decrease, so, if condition cant be used. Is there any other way

Comment: You can always use section property irrespective of number of sections in your tableView. It will always point to the correct section.

Comment: have a look at the answer by @deepak Bharathi below, there he have used "if" condition, as he is doing statically, but I am doing it dynamically, can U get me some info, instead of using "if" condition

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //get the name and phoneNo from currently selected cell.
    NSString *name = cell.yourCustomView.nameLabel.text;
    NSString *phoneNo = cell.yourCustomView.phoneNoLabel.text;

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        //code for section 1 selected
        YourNextViewController *nvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNextViewControllerIdentifier"];
        nvc.nameProperty = name;
        nvc.phoneNoProperty = phoneNo;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        //code for section 2 selected
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        //code for section 3 selected
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        //
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 4)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: I will be adding the values dynamically, so the number of sections will increase or decrease, so, if condition cant be used. Is ther any other way

Comment: @chandru Yes, there is.
You do not need to use any if condition just write method like this.
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *name = cell.yourCustomView.nameLabel.text;
NSString *phoneNo = cell.yourCustomView.phoneNoLabel.text;

YourNextViewController *nvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNextViewControllerIdentifier"];
nvc.nameProperty = name;
nvc.phoneNoProperty = phoneNo;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
}`

Comment: @chandru I got your point of dynamic number of sections.
Let me know, what actually do want to do on selection of the section.

If you are just using the same `NextViewController` with different values to pass, I don't think that any comparison is required.

Feel free to ask further doubt.

Comment: I am not using storyBoard, I will try to change it for my code, thank U

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic.

1) According to your views, each section have phone no & Name. So you can keep into one array which contains dictionary object.like below

```
[
  {
     name : "Chandru"
     phoneNo: "90xxxxxxxx"
   },
   ..........
]
```

2) So you can use this in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` as, `cell.nameLabel.text = [self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"name"];`

3) So you can pass it to next view as `nextVC.selectedPersonDetail = [self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

where `selectedPersonDetail` should be public property of NSDictionary. Otherwise you can use public method to hold as private variable.

Comment: What I am asking is that, I am just going to select a row, when I select it, didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is invoked, it should vary according to the section in which the row is selected

Comment: @chandru: as you mention, your tableview section should have one row. So what I've done above ,should be right answer to your condition.

Comment: the values will be dynamically added

Comment: Dynamically added to what? where do you add this?

Comment: The labels "name", "mobile number"

Comment: from Where? I think you have datasource to load data into tableview. If yes means, How do you load into it dynamically?

Comment: data will be loaded from database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43902/discussion-between-chandru-and-mani)